# EF navigation property include doesn't load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am trying to access the `Register` navigational property on my `RegisterCountLog`.. For some reason it is always null. So when I try access RegisterName it is always null.

```
public IQueryable<RegisterCountLog> GetCountsForDevice(long deviceSerial)
{
    return this.ServiceCollection.GetAll(c => c.Register)
               .Where(c => c.DeviceSerial == deviceSerial).AsNoTracking();
}
```

Note that `ServiceCollection.GetAll()` will (or should) include the `Register`.  The query after that specific bit aka `queryableLogs` is

```
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Contribution] AS [Contribution], 
    [Extent1].[DeviceSerial] AS [DeviceSerial], 
    [Extent1].[LogEntryID] AS [LogEntryID], 
    [Extent1].[RegisterId] AS [RegisterId], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    [Extent2].[RegisterId] AS [RegisterId1], 
    [Extent2].[DeviceSerial] AS [DeviceSerial1], 
    [Extent2].[RegisterName] AS [RegisterName], 
    [Extent2].[ZoneEntrance_ZoneEntranceID] AS [ZoneEntrance_ZoneEntranceID]
    FROM  [dbo].[RegisterCountLogs] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Registers] AS [Extent2] 
          ON  ([Extent1].[RegisterId] = [Extent2].[DeviceSerial]) 
          AND ([Extent1].[DeviceSerial] = [Extent2].[RegisterId])
```

Its used like so:

```
var queryableLogs = countLogService.GetCountsForDevice(serialNumber);
var groupedLogs= gLogs
    .Select(r => new Register
    {
        RegisterId = r.FirstOrDefault().RegisterId,
        RegisterName = r.FirstOrDefault().Register.RegisterName, // Here!
        DeviceSerial = r.FirstOrDefault().DeviceSerial,
        CountLogs = r.GroupBy(rc => 
                              new {Day = SqlFunctions
                                        .DatePart("dy", rc.Timestamp)})
                     .Select(rl => new RegisterCountLog()
                                   {
                                     Value = rl.to FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                     Timestamp = rl.FirstOrDefault()
                                                   .Timestamp,
                                   })
                     .OrderByDescending(l => l.Timestamp)
                     .ToList()
    })
    .Where(r=>r.CountLogs.Count() > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.RegisterId)
    .ToList();
```

Everything works perfectly except the `RegisterName` is always null.  If I check out the query `Register` is null too.  Why isnt it being loaded?

Here are the EF classes

```
public class RegisterCountLog
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Register")]
    public long DeviceSerial { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public long LogEntryID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("Register")]
    public long RegisterId { get; set; }

    public long Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public Register Register { get; set; }
}

public class Register
{
    public enum ContributionType
    {
        FlowIn,
        FlowOut
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long RegisterId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Device"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public long DeviceSerial { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RegisterName { get; set; }

    public ContributionType Contribution { get; set; }    

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make register virtual to enable lazy loading or use the `.Include(x => x.Register)` method when fetching your collection of `RegisterCountLog` to eager load.

Comment: `.GetAll()` should pre-load it (im using repository pattern),  I tried with virtual too but that didnt work.. Ill try again just in case

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using eager loading and you must specify `.Include(x => x.Register)` or `.Include("Register")`, depends on your EF version

If you named your variables great there can be another issue (eager loading isn't great with grouped things). One approach is to enumerate the query (to list) before selecting something. (if there aren't  performance problems)

EDIT : as i read your previous comment, i really think is the group by issue ( group by changes your linq structure and include isn't working anympore )

Approach is this :

```
var groupedPersons     = db.Appointments
                        .Include_Service()
                        .Include_Location()
                        .Include_Room()
                        .IncludeEhr_Patient()
                        .IncludeEhr_Person()
                        .IncludeEhr_Personal()
                        .ToList() // see that i enumerate before i group by
                        .GroupBy(x => x.PersonId).Select()[.ToList()]
```